# C++ Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting `Segmentation fault: 11` error when trying to run my program (I'm quite a n00b with c++ so take it easy on me). I know it has something to do with memory allocation but I'm not sure what exactly I am doing wrong. Can anyone please help and spot the problem/s?

Basically I'm trying to chop one vector into many small vectors, and analyse each one separately.

```
std::vector<double> test::getExactHit(std::vector<double> &hitBuffer, double threshold){

    int resolution = 100;
    int highestRMSBin = 0;
    std::vector<double> exactHit(8192);
    double* rmsInEachBin = new double[hitBuffer.size()/resolution];
    double highestRMSValue = threshold;

    for(int i = 0; i<hitBuffer.size()-resolution; i+=resolution){
        std::vector<double>::const_iterator first = hitBuffer.begin() + i;
        std::vector<double>::const_iterator last = hitBuffer.begin() + i + resolution;
        std::vector<double> hitBufferBin(first, last);

        rmsInEachBin[i/resolution] = calcRMS(hitBufferBin);

        if(rmsInEachBin[i/resolution]>highestRMSValue){
            highestRMSValue = rmsInEachBin[i/resolution];
            highestRMSBin = i;
        }

    }

    for(int j = 0 ; j < exactHit.size(); j++) {
        exactHit[j]=hitBuffer[j+highestRMSBin];
    }

    return exactHit;
}
```

Comment: Why not use the debugger to narrow down the line that this occurs on?

Comment: `delete []` that `rmsInEachBin` somewhere! In fact, why don't you use a vector for that too?

Comment: looks like a good opportunity to brush up your debugger skills.

Comment: is there a chance that hitBuffer.size() < resolution?

Comment: @Claptrap, I agree, doing it now. @rwols, I tried deleting it but it doesn't work. should I just do `delete[] rmsInEachBin;` at the end of the code?

Comment: @Nevos why don't use a vector<double> instead?

Comment: @Claptrap, I could, but what are the pros in using a vector here?

Comment: @Nevos the pros is that you do not need to delete [] and you would get an exception if you use .at( index ) when accessing outside the array, with a native array you will not necessarily notice and out of bounds situation.

Answer (score 1):

Please deallocate all the memory assigned using new or else it will cause memory leak and other bugs also might get introduced because of this . 
http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html
You  can debug using GDB , It will be handy to know a debugger if you are programming in C++ .
Hope this info will help you .